# config mail on laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, laravel-mail

i want config mail on laravel 5.2, i have a hosting mail with hostinger.com.

how i can configure mail parameters on laravel??

i put this on the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.co
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=reset-password@litraen.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

but when i try send email, show this error:

Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181:

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "reset-password@litraen.com" using 2 possible authenticators

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `MAIL_PORT=25` in your settings.
*(In case it is not a mistake)*

Also check if the port 25 of your system is not already taken or closed.

If your mail configuration uses SSL, you might use:
`MAIL_PORT=465`

[This](https://www.habschned.com/hostinger-com-no-longer-offers-smtp-for-free-accounts/) read also might help.

Comment: This saved alot of time. Thanks!